# Policy body to install an Application on the Managed device using AndroidManagement API

Tags: c#, json, mdm, policy, android-management-api

I'm building an MDM application using Google's AndroidManagement API in a C# Console application and I have created a policy for the device as well which has the default values.

I'm trying to create an Application Policy to install a new app package on the device and all the blogs suggest to add the application policy in a JSON :

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.example",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "lockTaskAllowed": true,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "example2",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "lockTaskAllowed": false,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "example3",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "lockTaskAllowed": true,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
  "cameraDisabled": true,
  "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
  "adjustVolumeDisabled" :  true
}
```

And the Policy body instance is created :

`public static Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Policy body = new Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data.Policy();`

Json loads perfectly but the `application policy lists` cannot be saved into the `ApplicationPolicy` because of type conversions.

```
{
    var appPolicy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(File.ReadAllText(applicationPolicyJson));

    policyBody.CameraDisabled = appPolicy.CameraDisabled;
    policyBody.ScreenCaptureDisabled = appPolicy.ScreenCaptureDisabled;
    policyBody.AdjustVolumeDisabled = appPolicy.AdjustVolumeDisabled;

    policyBody.Applications = new List<ApplicationPolicy> {***appPolicy*** };
}


public class Rootobject
{
   public Application[] Applications { get; set; }
   public bool CameraDisabled { get; set; }
   public bool ScreenCaptureDisabled { get; set; }
   public bool AdjustVolumeDisabled { get; set; }
}
public class Application
{
   public string PackageName { get; set; }
   public string InstallType { get; set; }
   public bool LockTaskAllowed { get; set; }
   public string DefaultPermissionPolicy { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the C# library you cannot "load" the JSON directly, the [Patch](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1AndroidManagement_1_1v1_1_1EnterprisesResource_1_1PoliciesResource.html#a51c0528814bb0a13da251534edde080f) method takes a [Policy](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1AndroidManagement_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Policy.html) object that you need to build using C# semantics. It's the same for Java. On the other hand the Python library takes a dictionary which is easy to generate from a JSON.

For C# this would look like:

```
using Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data;

var policy = new Policy();

policy.CameraDisabled = true;
policy.ScreenCaptureDisabled = true;
policy.AdjustVolumeDisabled = true;

var app1 = new ApplicationPolicy();
app.PackageName = "com.android.chrome";
app.InstallType = "FORCE_INSTALLED";
app.LockTaskAllowed = true;
app.DefaultPermissionPolicy = "GRANT";

var app2 = new ApplicationPolicy();
app.PackageName = "com.example";
app.InstallType = "FORCE_INSTALLED";

policy.Applications = new List<ApplicationPolicy> {app1, app2};
```

Disclaimer: I'm not used to C#, so it's possible that this code doesn't compile, but hopefully that gives you the idea.

Comment: Hey thank you! 
I'm aware of this procedure but want to get it done from a JSON because the response from the front end is a JSON.

I think it's best to create a class model and replicate the JSON structure and loads values into C# variables.

Anyways, appreciate your help.

Comment: You can add additional elements to the `policy.Applications` array. I updated my response to show an example.

Comment: Ah thanks! But since I want to get this from a json which might have different number of ApplicationPolicy and each one of it can be unique. Hoping to find a way to just consume a json as list. var appPolicy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(File.ReadAllText(applicationPolicyJson)); I've done this it works exactly as I want by create 3 application policies as list but unable to put it into the application body because of the type.

I've updated the question as well, please have a look.

Comment: I see. I think if DeserializeObject cannot deserialize to Policy or ApplicationPolicy directly then you will have to implement your own converted function from Application to ApplicationPolicy.